# What are other ways of saying "walk all over someone"?

Tags: phrase-requests

What are other ways of saying "walk all over someone" or take advantage of them?

Is there a one word phrase to describe this? I'm sure there is, I just can't think

Comment: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11865/warn-people-of-the-rules-for-single-word-requests-before-posting?cb=1

Answer (score 1):

You can **bully** someone.

You can **mistreat** someone.

You can **use** someone.

You can **abuse** someone.

You can **exploit** someone.

You can **browbeat** someone.

Answer (score 0):

to **trample upon**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/trample+on) an idiom

trample on (someone or something)

> 2. To destroy, debase, or dismiss something through rough, abrasive, or insensitive treatment.

As in:

> The professor really **trampled on** my ambitions when she critiqued my
>   thesis.

and

The people were trodden down by tyrants.