# Is there a word for when someone uses a relationship to get an advantage / promoted?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm thinking of a verb, or maybe a saying, to be used in the following manner: He'd cheated, lied, and (question word) to get to the top.

Preferably, the word or phrase would have something to do with manipulation, because he intentionally created these relationships to exploit them for his personal benefit.

Admittedly, the sentence could be reworded as "He'd cheated, lied, created and then destroyed relationships to get to the top," but that feels a little clunky.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason 'exploited [others]' is unacceptable? 'Manipulated' fits too, but you can check for synonyms you might prefer. 'Trampling on others' is a common metaphor.

Comment: Probably a duplicate: [What are other ways of saying _walk all over someone_?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/484642/what-are-other-ways-of-saying-walk-all-over-someone/484686#484686)

Comment: Now that you say it, i think "manipulated" could very well work here. When writing this question, I wanted to include the aspect of creating a relationship (in order to exploit it), but I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: Brown nosed his way to the top? You’re not very clear on the nature of the manipulation...

Comment: @lєαf I provided an answer, then deleted it. I had said that *exploited* was the word you wanted, but you've already used *manipulated* and *exploited* in the question itself. So, why have you rejected them?

Comment: Tbh I'm not quite sure why. As I was writing the question, I had in mind not a word, but rather an idea that I was having trouble putting into words. "Exploit" doesn't necessarily imply that trust was given and then broken, which was what I sought here.. "Manipulated" fit the bill, but it was mentioned as an afterthought because it didn't necessarily imply that my character sought a higher social standing.

Comment: *He [**inveigled**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/inveigle) his way into senior management*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context most English speakers would understand "use" as what you describe.

"Their relationship wasn't true, he used her to get promotions."

"He was just using her"

If the speaker was the "she" in question, she could say, "He used me."

While not strictly literal, it is common to say such a phrase and if I had to define "use" in this context I would describe it as "befriending someone into a relationship (any level of relationship, could be friendship, boyfriend/girlfriend, spouse) only for personal gain, not because of true feelings."

So, your description of

> he intentionally created these relationships to exploit them for his personal benefit.

would perfectly align with "use." The sentence you provided could be reworded as: "He'd used [them] to get to the top."

Comment: Right, "He'd cheated, lied, and *used people* to get to the top."

Comment: @RichardKayser I would go as far as to say that saying "used" is enough to imply that the person cheated and lied. If the speaker wants to say in definitive terms that they cheated and lied though, I wouldn't consider it redundant to specify such.

Comment: Agree. Was simply following the OP’s example sentence. I. The other hand, he could have cheated and lied beyond using people, e.g., on tests, forms.

Answer (score 1):

Nepotism

I have to add 30 more characters for this to be considered an answer.......

Comment: Hi Catherine, welcome to the site!  Actually what you really need to add is a definition (plus its source) and an explanation of how it fits into the requested usage.... :-)  Nepotism is a good noun for using a pre-existing familial relationship to place someone, but you can't really 'nepotise" your way to the top.

Answer (score 0):

The definitions of the terms favouritism, cronyism, and nepotism are brought together in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepotism).

Favouritism is the practice of promoting or appointing someone because they are part of an 'in' group rather than because of their inherent ability

Cronyism is similar but relates to promoting or appointing close personal friends of a person with influence rather than their membership of a wider group

Nepostism is, usually, the expression of a similar bias but for relatives rather than friends of the influential person.

None of these, of course, is practiced *by* the ambitious person, they would be practiced by people in senior positions on his behalf. But he could be said to have **courted favouritism** (or cronyism, or nepotism). In other words he could have suggested to the more powerful people with whom he had forged a close relationship that they practice favouritism, cronism or nepotism for his benefit.